# Haskell Export Record for Read Access Only

Tags: haskell, record, encapsulation, accessor

I have a Haskell type that uses record syntax.

```
data Foo a = Foo { getDims :: (Int, Int), getData :: [a] }
```

I don't want to export the `Foo` value constructor, so that the user can't construct invalid objects. However, I would like to export `getDims`, so that the user can get the dimensions of the data structure. If I do this

```
module Data.ModuleName(Foo(getDims)) where
```

then the user can use `getDims` to get the dimensions, but the problem is that they can also use record update syntax to update the field.

```
getDims foo -- This is allowed (as intended)
foo { getDims = (999, 999) } -- But this is also allowed (not intended)
```

I would like to prevent the latter, as it would put the data in an invalid state. I realize that I could simply not use records.

```
data Foo a = Foo { getDims_ :: (Int, Int), getData :: [a] }

getDims :: Foo a -> (Int, Int)
getDims = getDims_
```

But this seems like a rather roundabout way to work around the problem. Is there a way to continue using record syntax while only exporting the record name for read access, not for write access?

Comment: No, there isn't. Note that your latter example is the standard way of achieving this, and still uses records. What you call 'roundabout' is actually only two extra lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiding the constructor and then defining new accessor functions for each field is a solution, but it can get tedious for records with a large number of fields.

Here's a solution with the new [`HasField`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html#t:HasField) typeclass in [GHC 8.2.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#record-field-selector-polymorphism) that avoids having to define functions for each field.

The idea is to define an auxiliary newtype like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}    
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-} -- Important, obscure errors happen without this.

import GHC.Records (HasField(..))

-- Do NOT export the actual constructor!
newtype Moat r = Moat r

-- Export this instead.
moat :: r -> Moat r
moat = Moat

-- If r has a field, Moat r also has that field
instance HasField s r v => HasField s (Moat r) v where
    getField (Moat r) = getField @s r
```

Every field in a record `r` will be accesible from `Moat r`, with the following syntax:

```
λ :set -XDataKinds
λ :set -XTypeApplications
λ getField @"getDims" $ moat (Foo (5,5) ['s'])
(5,5)
```

The `Foo` constructor should be hidden from clients. However, the field accessors for `Foo` should *not* be hidden; they must be in scope for the `HasField` instances of `Moat` to kick in.

*Every* function in your public-facing api should return and receive `Moat Foo`s instead of `Foo`s.

To make the accessor syntax slightly less verbose, we can turn to [`OverloadedLabels`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-labels):

```
import GHC.OverloadedLabels

newtype Label r v = Label { field :: r -> v }

instance HasField l r v => IsLabel l (Label r v)  where
    fromLabel = Label (getField @l)
```

In ghci:

```
λ :set -XOverloadedLabels
λ field #getDims $ moat (Foo (5,5) ['s'])
(5,5)
```

---

Instead of hiding the `Foo` constructor, another option would be to make `Foo` completely public and define `Moat` inside your library, hiding any `Moat` constructors from clients.